# Array doesn't show in Table

Tags: jquery, typescript

I want the Function FilterUser to show the array UserFilter in a table, however, it doesn't work. When I console.log the first function, it gives me the correct array, but somehow, it doesn't show up on the table. Do you know how to change the function to make it work?

```
function searchUser() {
  UserFilter = users.filter(function(User) {
    if (User.uName.search(inputSearch.val().toString()) > -1) {
      return true
      FilterUser();

    } else {
      return false;
    }
  });

  console.log(UserFilter)
}


function FilterUser() {
  tableUser.empty();

  for (let i: number = 0; i < UserFilter.length; i++) {
    const user: User = UserFilter[i];
    const tr: JQuery = $(`
        <tr>
            <td>${user.fName}</td>
            <td>${user.lName}</td>
            <td>${user.uName}</td>
            <td>
                <button class="btn btn-outline-dark btn-sm btnEdit" data-id="${i}">
                    <i class="fa fa-pencil-alt"></i>
                </button>
                <button class="btn btn-outline-dark btn-sm btnDel" data-id="${i}">
                    <i class="fa fa-trash"></i>
                </button>
            </td>
        </tr>
        `);

    tableUser.append(tr);
  }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Your first function returns true before calling FilterUser